# PyCharm Type Hints are ambiguous for nested dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am getting the below warning from Pycharm while trying to access a nested dict. Here is the code to reproduce the behaviour:

```
response = dict()
response['id'] = 'abc'
response['data'] = dict()
response['data']['field'] = {'value': 10,
                               'confidence': None,
                               'source': 'raw',
                               }
value = response['data']['field']['value']
```

While trying to access the "value", Pycharm complains about the following warning:
`Expected type 'Union[int, slice]', got 'str' instead`

Can someone please help me understand this behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering why PyCharm is doing any type-checking at all. Ignoring that, the problem might be the inferred return type for `response.__getitem__`, which is `Union[str,dict]` When you use `response['data']`, PyCharm seems to only look at the type of `str.__getitem__`, not `dict.__getitem__`, as the relevant type hint for `response['data'].__getitem__`, as `response['id']['field']` would certainly be a problem.

Comment: I don't understand it either, and adding annotations doesn't seem to make a difference. Consider reporting this as a defect to JetBrains. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reporting-issues.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'm seeing:

Pycharm is only auto typing one or two levels deep.  (not sure if there is anything you can do about that part). I also agree (as others have pointed out) that the auto-type hinting doesn't make sense to me either. (likely there is a bug there)

However, when I put in my own type hints I can get the warning to go away. (currently using 2020.1)

```py
response: Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[int,str,None]]]]] = dict()
```

Personally I find that super ugly and hard to read. Depending on how often these dictionaries are repeated I will sometimes write something like this:

```py
T_fieldD = Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[int,str,None]]]
T_respD = Dict[str, Union[str, T_fieldD]]

response: T_respD = dict()
```

Comment: `response: dict[str, Any] = {}` worked for me, Pycharm is silent that way

Comment: That makes sense.  `Any` effectively turns off the type checker for that portion.